# Distance detection using two webcams/images

Tags: image-processing, python-2.7, webcam, raspberry-pi, rubber-band

I'm in the starting blocks of trying to figure out how I can get the distance to any given point in an image. Given just a single image this is off course impossible without knowing the size of the objects I want to know the distance too and defining what this means in pixels..

The idea I have in mind for doing this is to mount two 720p webcams facing the same direction at a known distance to each other.. around 4 inches.. and then trying to compare the offset of the items in the image to try to get a fairly accurate guess of the distance (I only need this to work in the range of around 3 to 12 feet).

The idea I have for the algorithm goes along the lines of:

1. Capture two images at same point in time from the two separate cameras.
2. Select small area in image 1 that I want to know the distance to.
3. Try to align the chosen spot in the 1st image to the same spot in 2nd image.
4. When I have aligned them I should be able to calculate the distance, knowing how much I had to adjust the images to match each other.

So what I'm looking for help with is how point 3 in the list should be done, aligning the images.. Or if anyone has any completly different ideas for how this should be done I'm all ears.

As a side note, I want to run this in python on a raspberry pi so I need to do all calculations with a minimum of processing power.

This is going to be used in the context of an automatic rubber-band sentry gun. The parts above will be used to calculate at what incline the shots need to be fired to compensate for the rubber bands trajectory.

Comment: I have already managed to capture an image on the raspberry and detect if there is any motion by subtracting the previous frame from the new frame.

Comment: This a well known problem. Google will help if you use terms like "multiple view geometry", "stereo rectification", "epipolar geometry", and so on ...